# How can I save a Rconsole position as default?

Tags: r

Every time I open the Rconsole, it is behind my taskbar (because I use it on the top of the screen). I already put xconsole and yconsole equals to zero on my Rconsole file but it didn't work. I'm using Windows 10 version 1909 and R 3.6.3.

Here is my desktop and the window position:
[image: My desktop]

Comment: Are you using the native R GUI or [RStudio](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)?

Comment: @Tung the native one

Comment: then you should consider switching to RStudio. Much much better than the native one (which is pretty bad)

Comment: See more about RStudio here https://blog.rstudio.com/categories/rstudio-ide/

Comment: @Tung Yes, I know RStudio, I just want to solve my problem with the Rconsole.